# Как оставить в массиве временных данных только те строки, которые идут подряд?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, временные-ряды

У меня есть лист ecxel в котором содержаться данные температуры за каждый день. Мне нужно выделить устойчивый период (начало и конец), когда температура выше 0 градусов. Период устойчив, если температура поднялась выше 0 и не опускается или опускается ниже 0, но не больше 2 дней подряд. Период считается законченным, если температура опустилась ниже 0 и больше не поднималась за этот год. Я смог выделить только дни с положительными температурами, а вот додуматься как именно выделить устойчивый период пока не могу.

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
wb = xw.Book('Temp1.xlsx')
data_excel = wb.sheets['Лист1']
data_pd = data_excel.range('A1:E1828').options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=False).value
temp0 = data_pd[data_pd['Темп'] >= 0.0]
```

Ссылка на экселевский файл https://yadi.sk/i/J6QIAbjlbuhPdg

Comment: Надеюсь, при обратном переводе с английского фрагмент [про вспомогательный логический массив](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65250212/14094617) всё ещё будет понятен - там не Python, куски кода на VBA, но принцип должен быть понятен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Temp1.xlsx")
df.dropna(inplace=True) # удаляем строки с отсутствующими данными
df["Stable"] = False    # создаем колонку с признаком стабильности периода 

# ищем группы последовательных дат с минусовыми температурами длиной не более 2 дней:
for i, g in df[df['Темп'] < 0].groupby((df['Темп'] >= 0).cumsum()):
    if len(g) <=2 :
        df.loc[g.index, "Stable"] = True
    
# присваиваем признак стабильности всем датам с положительной температурой:
df.loc[df["Темп"]>=0, "Stable"] = True

# находим непрерывные группы дат с положительной температурой и температурой ниже 0
# не более двух дней подряд:

for i, g in df[df['Stable'] == True].groupby((df['Stable'] == False).cumsum()):
# здесь можно добавить условие, какая минимальная длина стабильного периода нужна
    print(f"Стабильный период - начало: {g['Дата'].iloc[0].date()}, конец: {g['Дата'].iloc[-1].date()}")
```

Получаем:

```
Стабильный период - начало: 2016-02-28, конец: 2016-02-28
Стабильный период - начало: 2016-03-13, конец: 2016-03-14
Стабильный период - начало: 2016-03-18, конец: 2016-10-01
Стабильный период - начало: 2016-10-06, конец: 2016-10-12
Стабильный период - начало: 2016-12-01, конец: 2016-12-01
...
Стабильный период - начало: 2020-03-13, конец: 2020-03-17
Стабильный период - начало: 2020-03-21, конец: 2020-03-22
Стабильный период - начало: 2020-03-27, конец: 2020-10-29
Стабильный период - начало: 2020-11-02, конец: 2020-11-02
Стабильный период - начало: 2020-11-07, конец: 2020-11-12
```

**UPDATE**

Для получения наибольшего стабильного периода и суммы его неотрицательных температур можно сделать так:

```
longest = sorted(df[df['Stable'] == True].groupby((df['Stable'] == False).cumsum()), key=lambda x: (len(x[1])))[-1][1]
print(f"Наибольший стабильный период - начало: {longest['Дата'].iloc[0].date()}, конец: {longest['Дата'].iloc[-1].date()}")
tempsum = longest.loc[longest["Темп"]>=0, "Темп"].sum()
print(f"Сумма ноетрицательных температур за наибольший стабильный период: {tempsum:.2f}")
```

Получим:

```
Наибольший стабильный период - начало: 2020-03-27, конец: 2020-10-29
Сумма неотрицательных температур за наибольший стабильный период: 2735.60
```

**UPDATE 2**

Чтобы получить несколько стабильных периодов с нужной длиной и сумму температур:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Temp1.xlsx")
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df["Stable"] = False
for i, g in df[df['Темп'] < 0].groupby((df['Темп'] >= 0).cumsum()):
    if len(g) <=2 :
        df.loc[g.index, "Stable"] = True
    
df.loc[df["Темп"]>=0, "Stable"] = True
for i, g in df[df['Stable'] == True].groupby((df['Stable'] == False).cumsum()):
    if len(g) > 5: # минимальная длительность периода (6 дней и выше)
        tempsum = g.loc[g["Темп"]>=0, "Темп"].sum()
        print(f"Стабильный период - начало: {g['Дата'].iloc[0].date()}, конец: {g['Дата'].iloc[-1].date()}")
        print(f"Сумма неотрицательных температур за данный период: {tempsum:.2f}")
```

Результат:

```
Стабильный период - начало: 2016-03-18, конец: 2016-10-01
Сумма ноетрицательных температур за данный период: 2481.90
Стабильный период - начало: 2016-10-06, конец: 2016-10-12
Сумма ноетрицательных температур за данный период: 3.30
Стабильный период - начало: 2017-03-23, конец: 2017-04-02
Сумма ноетрицательных температур за данный период: 43.70
Стабильный период - начало: 2017-04-07, конец: 2017-10-23
Сумма ноетрицательных температур за данный период: 2522.10
Стабильный период - начало: 2018-03-17, конец: 2018-03-30
Сумма ноетрицательных температур за данный период: 21.70
Стабильный период - начало: 2018-04-06, конец: 2018-10-31
Сумма ноетрицательных температур за данный период: 2570.20
Стабильный период - начало: 2019-02-19, конец: 2019-02-24
Сумма ноетрицательных температур за данный период: 3.90
Стабильный период - начало: 2019-03-22, конец: 2019-10-09
Сумма ноетрицательных температур за данный период: 2509.80
Стабильный период - начало: 2019-10-13, конец: 2019-10-19
Сумма ноетрицательных температур за данный период: 54.30
Стабильный период - начало: 2019-10-24, конец: 2019-11-02
Сумма ноетрицательных температур за данный период: 32.70
Стабильный период - начало: 2020-03-27, конец: 2020-10-29
Сумма ноетрицательных температур за данный период: 2735.60
Стабильный период - начало: 2020-11-07, конец: 2020-11-12
Сумма ноетрицательных температур за данный период: 24.60
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.
Я пока не додумался как прописать условие, чтобы выводился период с максимальной длиной. Перепробовал все что пока умею, выдает ошибки. Может у вас есть идеи?
И еще другой вопрос: можно ли дописать строку так, чтобы считалась сумма всех значений температур, которые попадают в период, но так, чтобы отрицательные значения не попали в расчет?

Comment: я обновил ответ

Comment: А как сделать так чтобы выводился период и сумма его температур?
Я прописал условие, для минимальной длинны периода, но как прописать его сумму температур?
for i, g in df[df['Stable'] == True].groupby((df['Stable'] == False).cumsum()):
    #tempsum = longest.loc[longest["Темп"] >= 0, "Темп"].sum()
    if len(g) >= 50:
        # сумма температур за каждый год
        print(f"Стабильный период - начало: {g['Дата'].iloc[0].date()}, конец: {g['Дата'].iloc[-1].date()}")